# Delphi XE6 Firemonkey Mobile - How to disable Virtual Keyboard?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, virtual-keyboard

When I focus an edit-field on Android the virtual keyboard always popup.
I like to disable this, or better to enable/disable this with the click of a button.

Currently I "solved" this with an timer that always closes the virtual keyboard after
appearing. This is my code:

```
uses FMX.VirtualKeyboard;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var Keyboard: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
    if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService,Keyboard) then
    begin
        if TVirtualKeyBoardState.Visible in Keyboard.GetVirtualKeyBoardState then
        begin
            Keyboard.HideVirtualKeyboard;
        end
    end;
end;
```

I hope youi can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.VKAutoShowMode

Comment: BTW you do not need to cast `IInterface( Keyboard )` just use it direct `TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, Keyboard)`

Answer (score 2):

You can disable automatic display of the virtual keyboard with

```
VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Never;
```

It is defined in FMX.Types.

Put that in your DPR and then it will no longer automatically popup.

Comment: Working with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and Android 6 it doesn't work.
I've put this code in the .DPROJ file, just after `Application.Initialize`. Is this the correct place?

Comment: Correction: I thought it was the .dproj file but it seems to be the .dpr file. But it doesn't work. @Jim McKeeth any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can also place:

```
VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Never;
```

in FormCreate event of main form.